# How do I implement a console with ssh features in C?

Tags: c, linux, console-application

That is,it should support up/down arrow keys and `ctrl-r` to reverse searching. WHere should I start?

Comment: Do you want all of SSH features, or just the ability to have command history?

Comment: If you mean that you want the nice line-editing features, investigate the GNU readline library, which supplies these features to many of the programs you see them in.

Comment: those items are not ssh features, they are features of the shell (bash/tcsh/zsh), which likely uses readline to implement them.

Comment: @Alan ,I only need those mentioned features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how low-level you want to be.  using `readline` or `editline` are the high-level answers.  Next level down would be to use `libncurses` and call `getch()` to read keyboard input, and then handle the history/searching yourself.

Lowest level (for a terminal) is handling the actual input stream of bytes. The arrow keys send particular character sequences depending on your particular terminal.   For example, a vt100 emulator will send ^[[A for "up-arrow", ^[[B for "down-arrow", and so forth.  To read these, you'll need to set your terminal attributes to return input immediately and not wait for a newline;  to do this use `termios` functions to disable canonical input mode.  Then just read input a character at a time, and see if you get characters (27, 91, 65) and you know that's an up-arrow and respond accordingly.

This low level is tedious and fragile and won't work if you use a different terminal emulator (although you could use `terminfo` to get the appropriate input sequences for other terminals.)

If you're at a lower level than a terminal (serial line, X window, bitmap display, whatever), then the answers change again.